# weight lattice vector which is not a weight of any representation

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

What is an example of a simply connected Lie group $ G $ and an integral vector $ \lambda $ (i.e. a vector in the weight lattice) such that $ \lambda $ is not a weight of any finite dimensional representation of $ G $?

Background: For a compact simply connected group $ G $ every integral vector $ \lambda $ a the weight of some finite dimensional representation. So the example $ G $ I'm asking for above cannot be compact.

Comment: When you say "_the_ weight of" do you mean actually "_a_ weight of"? Or, conceivably, because of the "the", "the highest weight"? Can you clarify?

Comment: @paulgarrett you're right I changed it to "a" weight, should be clearer now